# Group multiple iOS applications

Tags: ios, bundle, app-bundle

Let me set the stage first. Say a larger organization has a single iOS application. This worked just fine in the past, with new features being added to the app. The problem is that the application has become too large and hence difficult to manage. Cramming all new functionality into a single app is no longer feasible. To make things worse, organization does not want to have mutliple applications, as it would lead to fragmented user experience, which is not ideal. Question is... Is there something similar to "App Bundles" that would allow users to install multiple applications belonging to same organization without the need to individually install them? Unfortunately "App Bundles" require tier 1 applications (i.e. paid ones).

Comment: How would app bundles not be a fragmented user experience? Do you just mean how the user acquires the app/s? Also seems more like a design issue than a technical one. Couldn't you have all the 'apps' available from a home screen on a single app? Launching from there could send the user to the app store if they're missing an app.

Comment: Or just have setting to turn parts of the app on and off, just reduces the menu options...

Comment: Thanks @JoeSusnick , that is an option indeed. Ideally, would prefer that all applications within the "bundle" be installed in one go. The concern is not so much a technical one, but rather an organizational one. It also impacts overall agility. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing similar to "App Bundles" on iOS other than App Bundles.

However, you can have multiple apps in the store and use a url scheme for each app to see if a particular app can be launched when needed by a user -- for example, from a menu.

```
let appURL = NSURL(string: "myscheme://")
let appStoreURL = NSURL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/myappname/id99999999?mt=8")

if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(appURL!)){
    // app is installed, launch it
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(appURL!)
} else {
    // app is not installed, go get it
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(appStoreURL!)
}
```

If not, you can deep link to the correct page in the app store and the user can install them.  We use this technique to provide a way for users to access our constellation of apps from a single "launcher" app.

Comment: Thanks @Mathew, I like your approach. I will think about ways to implement this in our case.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many "subApps" you have I would recommend a tabBarController. I personally did this in a case similar to yours where we were adding new features to our app. You could also group this with @Wain 's idea to have a toggle feature to turn on or off parts of the app.